# $X$ path connected space simple connected if only if map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ extends to $D^2 \rightarrow X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, path-connected

I do not know how to approach this proof. Any hints about how to prove this?

$X$ path connected space simple connected if only if map $S^1 \rightarrow X$ extends to $D^2 \rightarrow X$

Answer (score 1):

hint: Let $C(S^1):=(S^1 \times I)/\sim$ where $(x,1) \sim (y,1)$. Show that $C(S^1)$ is homeomorphic to the disk.

Let $F:S^1 \times I \to X$ be a map such that $F \mid_{S^1 \times \{1\}}$ is constant. Then it factors through the cone by the universal property of quotients.

Comment: Ok nice. But I still have some questions. With this, we get $\implies$, but I do not see where we are using that X is path connected. And also, we are extending a map $F:S^1 \times I \to X$ not $F:S^1  \to X$. And how this shows the other implication?

Comment: the point of the homeomorphism is that *if* you can extend a map to the disk, you can extend it to the cone (how?) Again, this is just a hint.

Comment: I though the hint was the first line and your were sketching the proof in the second one. Then, just one question to work with the hint. Why do we want to extend it to the cone?

Comment: Well, because if you have an extension of some map to the cone, you can construct from it a homotopy to the constant map

Comment: I didn't know that. I am taking my first course in algebraic topology now. I will work on that, thanks

Comment: No issue at all! It’s not 100% obvious. Try to think it through, and feel free to come back and ask questions if you get stuck :)